# Transplant all nuget packages to a project in a different solution

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2012, nuget

I'm trying to add ASP.net Identity 2.1 to an MVC 5 project that currently uses the (surprisingly quickly forgotten and replaced) universal membership providers.

This is rather a large number of changes because it requires getting OWIN up and running too... in short, it's a helluvalot of nuget packages and some code changes.

I've got a working MVC project built from nuget package [Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.Samples/2.1.0-alpha1). I'm going to crib almost everything from this project and transplant it into my target project (in a different solution).

I rather don't fancy switching between windows, checking version numbers and selecting packages or issuing individual 'Install-Package' commands in the package-manager console.

What's the quickest route to copy all the installed nuget packages from one project to another given that they exist in different solutions?

Comment: You could try to edit the packages.config file to contain the desired packages and then resolve them.

Comment: @JohanLarsson I'm currently exploring this avenue. I'm going to merge the package.config files with some code and see what happens.

Comment: I just tried it, it worked. Paste the rows with the desired packages and build. Building resolved the missing packages for me.

Comment: @JohanLarsson : I thought that this has solved it, but it actually only marks the packages as being installed in the package manager. It does not make any manipulation to the actual project that new packages appear in. When package restore runs, it only ensures that the packages are in the packages folder. The way I fixed this was first to run `Update-Package` to ensure all packages were up to date, then ran `Update-Package -Reinstall -IgnoreDependencies`, then unpicked some web.config settings that got overwritten during the reinstall. Doing this manually would have been quicker. :)